# Canvas/fabricJs Why is this font rendered differently on the frontend and backend even though it is the same font?

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, fonts, fabricjs

I'm working with **canvas** and **fabric.js 4.6.0**

I'm using a right-to-left (rtl) font called **Fb Absoluti Con** it's a Hebrew font, but for some reason it renders different in backend, it works good in frontend (browser) but it doesn't work if I want to generate a canvas and save it as an image, the font looks different.

this is the result in the **browser:**

[image: browser result]

That's the expected result.

And this is the result with **nodejs:**

[image: image with nodejs]

As you can see the result is different in nodejs, even if it is the same font. I'm adding the custom font to nodejs like this [Custom fonts in Fabric on Node](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-4#custom-fonts)

**this is the code for the frontend (good, expected result)**

```
    const fontFamily = 'Fb Absoluti Con';
    const canvasElmt = document.getElementById('canvas');
    const canvas = new fabric.Canvas(canvasElmt, {
        width: 400,
        height: 400,
        backgroundColor: 'lightgrey',
    });

    fabric.util.clearFabricFontCache(fontFamily);

    const txt = new fabric.Textbox('זיידענפעלד', {
        left: 10,
        top: 20,
        fontFamily,
        fontWeight: 600,
        direction: 'rtl',
        textAlign: 'right',
        fontSize: 40
    });
    canvas.add(txt);
    canvas.renderAll();

    function forceRenderUpdate() {
        for (const obj of canvas.getObjects()) {
            const originalFontSize = obj.fontSize;
            obj.fontSize = obj.fontSize + 3;
            canvas.renderAll();
            obj.fontSize = originalFontSize;
            canvas.renderAll();
        }
    }

    const fontObserver = new FontFaceObserver(fontFamily);

    fontObserver.load('זיידענפעלד', 2000).then(() => {
        console.log('font loaded');
        forceRenderUpdate();
    });
```

**this is the code for backend (bad, unexpected result)**

```
const { fabric } = require('fabric');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const fontFamily = 'Fb Absoluti Con';

// register font in nodeCanvas
fabric.util.clearFabricFontCache(fontFamily);
fabric.nodeCanvas.registerFont(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'fbabsoluti.otf'), {
    weight: 600, 
    family: fontFamily, 
    style: 'normal'
});

// create canvas and add text
const canvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas(null, {
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    backgroundColor: 'lightgrey',
});
const txt = new fabric.Textbox('זיידענפעלד', {
    left: 10,
    top: 20,
    fontFamily,
    fontWeight: 600,
    direction: 'rtl',
    textAlign: 'right',
    fontSize: 40
});
canvas.add(txt);
canvas.renderAll();

// generate base 64 and save image in disk
const b64 = canvas.toDataURL({ format: 'jpeg' }).split(',')[1];
fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'nodegenerated.jpg'), b64, { encoding: 'base64' });
console.log('finished');
```

I created a [**github repo**](https://github.com/coxato/fabricjs-customfont-issue) you can run and test it, the font file is included.

I don't know why it renders different in the backend, even if it is the same font, same file .otf